# Unexpected ambiguity between overloaded methods with long, int & short arguments

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Why is method((short)1,1,1); only ambiguous between the 2nd and 3rd method although it can also be implicitly casted to the first?
Why is it ambigious at all even though it needs less implicit casting for the 3rd than for the 2nd?

If the amount of implicit castings doesn't matter, why is method(1,1,1) not ambiguous between 1 and 2 although it can be implicitly casted to both?

```
public class Main {
    static void method(long x, long y, long z) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    static void method(int x, long y, int z) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    static void method(short x, int y, double z) {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method((short) 1, 1, 1); // ambiguous between 2 and 3
        method(1, 1, 1); // calls 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your *specific* technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

With `method(1, 1, 1);`, strict invocation finds two applicable methods: `method(long x, long y, long z)` and `method(int x, long y, int z)`. `method(short x, int y, double z)` is not applicable because [strict invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2) only allows widening primitives conversions. `int` to `long` is fine, but not `int` to `short`.

According to [§15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> One applicable method m1 is more specific than another applicable method m2, for an invocation with argument expressions e1, ..., ek, if any of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
> - m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2 has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, the type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).

And on type specificity:

> A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T

From [4.10.1. Subtyping among Primitive Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1), we have that `int` is considered a subtype of `long`. `method(int x, long y, int z)` is thus more specific than `method(long x, long y, long z)` since the type of each parameter is either the same or a subtype of the corresponding parameter of the latter method.

> A method m1 is strictly more specific than another method m2 if and only if m1 is more specific than m2 and m2 is not more specific than m1. 
> A method is said to be maximally specific for a method invocation if it is accessible and applicable and there is no other method that is accessible and applicable that is strictly more specific.

`method(long x, long y, long z)` is not more specific than `method(int x, long y, int z)`, so `method(int x, long y, int z)` is maximally specific. There are no other maximally specific methods, so it is the most specific method and will be called.

With `method((short) 1, 1, 1);`, all three methods are considered applicable by widening conversion.

However, `method(short x, int y, double z)` is not more specific than all the other two methods because `double` is not a subtype or `int` or a subtype of `long` (in fact, it is considered a supertype). Similarly, none of the other methods have a more specific first parameter type since `int` and `long` are supertypes of `short`.

We have no method that is strictly more specific than every other applicable method, so there is no single maximally specific method. Thus the call is ambiguous.

See [§15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) to read more about the whole process.